# For every $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$, there exists a corresponding solution $u(x,t)$ to the heat equation on a ring under specific conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

The following is an old exam question I'm stuck on:

Show that for every $f \in  C(\mathbb{T})$ (where $\mathbb{T} = [-\pi, \pi]$) there is an initial condition $g \in  C(\mathbb{T}$ for which there is a solution $u(x,t)$ to the heat equation on a ring with $u(x,0) = g(x)$ and $|u(x,1) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Using Fourier series, it can be shown that the solution is of the form $u(x,t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} g_n e^{-n^2 t} e^{inx}$. But if we want to meet the second condition for some $f$ of the form $f(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n e^{inx}$, then, we're left with $$|u(x,1) - f(x)| = \left| \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (f_n - g_n e^{-n^2})e^{inx} \right|.$$

Equating Fourier coefficients, this implies that $g_n = f_n e^{n^2}$, but the series defined by such $g_n$ isn't in $L^2$ or even convergent. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximate $f(x)$ uniformly by a trigonometric polynomial $h(x)$.  By Stone-Weierstrass this can be done. Then explicitly find a solution $u(x,t)$ such that $u(x,1) = h(x)$.

Comment: But my issue is that such a solution would be defined in terms of a Fourier series, but this series doesn't converge.

Comment: No, it is not the Fourier series, nor is it a partial sum of the Fourier series.  You can use the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), as I said, or you can use a Cesàro mean of the Fourier series: these do converge uniformly to the function, by [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem).